# Clearly initialized field throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing

I hate to be asking this, but I'm getting a NullPointerException with the two global variables `weakAcid` and `weakBase`, even though I clearly initialize those variables in the constructor. My code is below, and the error is in the addComponents() method, and is the exact line `panel.add(weakAcid, c)`. When I debugged, I found out that both fields failed to initialize. Help perhaps?

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at gametype.AcidBaseGame.addComponents(AcidBaseGame.java:112)
at gametype.Game.<init>(Game.java:55)
at gametype.SolubilityGame.<init>(SolubilityGame.java:17)
at gametype.AcidBaseGame.<init>(AcidBaseGame.java:25)
at gui.GameFrame.actionPerformed(GameFrame.java:132)
```

---

```
public class AcidBaseGame extends SolubilityGame
{

private JButton weakAcid;
private JButton weakBase;

private int buttonIndex;

public AcidBaseGame()
{
    /* hidden code to save space */

    weakAcid = new JButton("Weak Acid");
    weakBase = new JButton("Weak Base");

    endDisplay = new JLabel();

    //actionlisteners to buttons
    choice1.addActionListener(this);
    choice2.addActionListener(this);
    weakAcid.addActionListener(this);
    weakBase.addActionListener(this);

    this.addComponents();

}


private void setChemical()
{
    //hidden code
}

public void addComponents() 
{

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            //initializes fine
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(chemicalLabel, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(choice1, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(choice2, c);

            //error
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(weakAcid, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(weakBase, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(endDisplay, c);

}

public void determineCorrect() 
{
       //hidden code
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{

    //hidden code

}
```

}

Comment: maybe you can condense the code to the relevant parts that still show the troubling behavior?

Comment: And even provide the stack trace as this gives helpful information. From the code shown we cannot deduce the error.

Comment: Where is `panel` declared?

Comment: p.s. did you try running through this in debugger mode, check that weakAcid really is null and not (as some are suggesting) the panel. Always use debug, its really useful

Comment: I debugged, as I said, and Eclipse told me weakAcid and weakBase are null, not panel.

Comment: @collielimabean sorry, I didn't notice that, have you tried putting a debug break point right on top of weakAcid = new JButton("Weak Acid"); to check if it runs before the error occurs

Comment: @RichardTingle The code runs up until that point.

Comment: @collielimabean So you've confirmed that the declaration occurs before the exception. Because all parent classes constructors will run completely before the child class constructors (wether you explicitly call the parent class or not)

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, that is correct - I didn't realize that parent constructors ran all the way through regardless of whether super() is called or not, so the problem actually originated from a class structure issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: a parent class's constructor calls an overridden `addComponents()` method. When it does this, it will call the `addComponents()` method of the child class and will do so before you've initialized your components.

Note that there is danger when you have constructors call overridable methods and this is one reason why this sort of thing should be avoided. You may even want to re-evaluate if you should be using inheritance here, and I'm guessing that in fact you should not.

---

Edit:
You state in comment:

> In an earlier version, I called super(), but then I realized that it called addComponents() before I initialized. I modified my constructor so that it didn't use super().

You don't have to call `super()` constructor as it will automatically be called whether you want it to or not. All you can do is call a specific constructor of the super class that doesn't call addComponents() if desired. My suggestion: don't even use inheritance for this GUI. It adds no value and carries risk.

Comment: In an earlier version, I called super(), but then I realized that it called addComponents() before I initialized. I modified my constructor so that it didn't use super().

Comment: Ah, that would explain the error. I will modify my class and report back if it is okay.

Comment: nice and clean explanation. +1

Comment: I changed the class definition so that it extended the superclass of `SolubilityGame` (which is `Game`). The addComponents() method is not called in the `Game` constructor to allow subclasses to call the addComponents() whenever it initializes all. In other words, it works now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the stack trace, the following lines

```
at gametype.AcidBaseGame.addComponents(AcidBaseGame.java:112)
at gametype.Game.<init>(Game.java:55)
```

show that you are calling `addComponents` already in the constructor of class `Game`. At this time the initialization of `weakAcid` did not yet take place.